# Is there ANY way to have the three.js camera lookat being rendered off-center?

Tags: three.js, renderer

Is there a way to setup the Three.js renderer in such a way that the lookat point of the camera is not in the center of the rendered image?

To clarify: image a scene with just one 1x1x1m cube at ( 0, 0, 0 ). The camera is located at ( 0, 0, 10 ) and the lookat point is at the origin, coinciding with the center of the cube. If I render this scene as is, I might end up with something like this:

[normal render](http://test.moobels.com/temp/cube_front.jpg)

However I'd like to be able to render this scene in such a way that the lookat point is in the upper left corner, giving me something like this:

[desired render](http://test.moobels.com/temp/cube_desired.jpg)

If the normal image is 800x600, then the result I envision would be as if I rendered a 1600x1200 image with the lookat in the center and then cropped that normal image so that only the lower right part remains.

Of course, I can change the lookat to make the cube go to the upper left corner, but then I view the cube under an angle, giving me an undesired result like this:

test.moobels.com/temp/cube_angle.jpg

I could also actually render the full 1600x1200 image and hide 3/4 of the image, but one would hope there is a more elegant solution. Does anybody know it?

Comment: See if [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_grid.html) or [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_complex.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @WestLangley You sir, are a king sir.

Comment: @kevin your images are missing from the question, to help others could you attach them directly to your question?

Answer (score 13):

If you want your perspective camera to have an off-center view, the pattern you need to use is:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( for, aspect, near, far );
camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, viewX, viewY, viewWidth, viewHeight );
```

See the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/PerspectiveCamera

You can find examples of this usage in [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_grid.html) and [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_complex.html).

three.js r.73

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

Assuming your cube is 4 x 4 x 4, at position 0, 0, 0:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 4, 4, 4 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x777777 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
```

Get cube's position:

```
var Vx = cube.position.x, 
    Vy = cube.position.y, 
    Vz = cube.position.z;
```

Then deduct by 2 from x position, then add 2 to y and z position, and use the values to create a new Vector3:

```
var newVx = Vx - 2,
    newVy = Vy + 2;
    newVz = Vz + 2;

var xyz = new THREE.Vector3(newVx, newVy, newVz)
```

Then camera lookAt:

```
camera.lookAt(xyz);
```

Using console log, it would show that the camera is now looking at -2, 2, 2, which is the upper-left of your cube.

```
console.log(xyz);
```