# How to offset target position in ThreeJS controls

Tags: three.js

I am using ThreeJS's OrbitControls so that when an object in my scene is clicked, the camera travels close to it and and starts orbiting around it. I'm just moving the controls.target position, camera position and setting controls.autoRotate = true.

The clicked object gets centered on screen, which is nice, but sometimes I need to show a text covering up to 50% of the bottom area of the screen, and then the selected objects gets hidden by it. So, I'd need to somehow offset the rotation center up a bit.

Perhaps another way of asking this is that I need to change the center of rotation so that it is NOT the center of the screen (or the center of the renderer canvas)

I've tried moving the target up but, of course, then the camera doesn't orbit around the selected 3D object but around an empty space close to it. Any idea on how to proceed?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the desired results following the comments in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092430/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-three-js-camera-lookat-being-rendered-off-center):

by using [camera.setViewOffset](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setViewOffset)